# Hyper-V kills internet connection when bridging

Tags: hyper-v

I am using Hyper-V for the first time (running Windows 8). When I create a new virtual network switch, external, it bridges the VMs network adapter with the WiFi - and that for some reason kills the WiFi's internet connection. Why, and what could I be doing wrong?

Thanks,
A.

Comment: are you still experimenting this? in my case, it happens ocassionally, and sometimes I have to disconnect everything and enable it again and again, this is getting on my nerves

Comment: I stopped using it - happened at lot. I have to disable and enable it, and never found a solution to it. Very odd!

Comment: This [serverfault answer](http://serverfault.com/a/446325) points out that Hyper-V Virtual Switches cannot be used with a WiFi NIC.

Comment: This detailed [superuser answer](http://superuser.com/a/472854/92681) may work for some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, it takes a couple of seconds to setup the connection again. Check this tutorial: https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access

Comment: Thanks, but I also tried that one earlier, and get the same result (just tried it once again). I waited minutes, so time is not the factor.

Comment: Weird, I had that problem too, when I followed the guide it worked. What I did though, was remove all VM's and setup the connection bewfor creating a new VM. Maybe it has to do something with it. Can you export the VM, enable the connection, then import it again?

Comment: I got it working, but I cannot find any logic in how. After creating the virtual network switch, I went Network Connections, and deleted the Network Bridge. I then disabled the WiFi, enabled it again, marked the two network adapters, and bridged them again. And then it worked. Go figure...

Comment: I didn't need to explicitly bridge the connection to use internet in the VM and in the hosting system.

Comment: When you run the virtual switch manager to make an external connection, it automatically makes a bridge.

Comment: @Anders I am facing an issue similar to OP's issue. However, for me the virtual switch gets created but the Bridge does not get created. Any pointers?

Comment: @Akash, in my case the bridge gets created automatically for WIFI only, but for Ethernet cable bridge was not created nor required. My interwebs access works fine whether Wifi or cable.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `VirtualBox`installed, check if any of the Hyper-V virtual adapters/bridge connection has the `VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver` ticked in the connection properties. If they do, simply untick this service where it is present and this should fix it up for you. No need to uninstall VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

I had a static ip-address in my ethernet adapter.
Removed the static entry.
Made my external virtual switch.
Had the extra vEthernet adapter, made my static entries (ip-address, dns-server) in this adapter.
Everything is working fine now.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem, losing the internet connection when creating the virtual switch. Uninstalling `VirtualBox` which I had installed at the same time fixed the problem for me (just disabling the VBox adapters was not enough), so they seem to be unable to happily coexist.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently when creating an external switch in Hyper-V. Long story short, every time an external switch was created, it would bring my ethernet connection down on my host laptop.  I had wifi connection option also but disabled it to just strictly troubleshoot the ethernet network adapter.

I brought down the VM, once turned off, deleted the external network adapter from hyper V virtual switch manager.  On the host machine, disabled and re-enabled the network adapter from within network connections (ethernet).  Once connected, I brought the VM back online FIRST, then created the external switch second which connected with no issues.  Verified I was able to access outside world aka internet on both host and VM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you unchecked by  accident the `Allow management OS to share this network adapter` setting that is enabled by default. Disabling this setting will leave your hypervisor OS without network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix such an issue by disabling Internet sharing on the wireless adapter, creating an Internal virtual switch in Hyper-V first, then disabling VMWare bridge on all involved interfaces, then I made a bridge in Network sharing center by selecting my internal switch and Wi-Fi adapter and after that I was able to select external network in Virtual switch manager in Hyper-V

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same problem too. I don't know for sure, but after trying all of the solutions above and any others I could find, I renamed my virtual switch to 'realtek' (the type of network card I have installed) instead of taking the default name that I think was 'new virtual switch'. Something else I did may have solved the problem (I modified everything I could find for two days), but I think renaming it is what finally gave me internet access to the vm.